# WiX: How to point the localized license (without `LicenseAgreementDlg` dialog edit)?

Tags: wix

WiX.
If I write this:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="!(loc.license)"/>
```

then I get the error:

> The system cannot find the file '!(loc.license)'.

If I write this:

```
<Property Id="LICENSE" Value="!(loc.license)"/>
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="$(var.LICENSE)"/>
```

then I get the error:

> Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.LICENSE)'

Why WiX doesn't extract the value of this `WixVariable`? Is it possible to point the localized license without edit the code source of the `LicenseAgreementDlg` dialog?

Comment: Hello, Were you able to get this working without editing the source code of LicenseAgreementDlg dialog?